# display json value as angular input @Input()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this template in app.component.html:

```
<test [someInput]="data"></test>
```

'data' is a json object property like:

```
let data = {hello : "ciao"}
```

This is my test.component.ts:

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input()
  someInput:string

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

This is my test.component.html template:

```
<p>{{someInput.hello}},test works!</p>
```

I think someInput will be replace with 'data' json propery name, and my browser will display "ciao",but i dont know where to place
definition of "let data ={hello:ciao} ?

IFi place in .ts, Chrome console give me an error:

```
TestComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TestComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
```

Comment: 1- Get rid of  `@Input() someInput:string`.
2- Write this data = {hello : "ciao"}  **WITHOUT LET** instead of the line you've got rid of in step 1.
3_  Use this instead the one in your code  <p>{{data.hello}},test works!</p>

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value as an [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) you need to do it in the HTML of the PARENT COMPONENT (the component that's using your test.component)

It should look like this

```html
<! -- some html here -->
<app-test [someInput]="helloData">
```

parent.component.ts

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  helloData = {hello: 'ciao'}

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: In addition  if you want pass an object ,  type of variable with decorator @Input has to be Object or any.